# How to conditionally add a child component to a parent component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-svg

Consider an array like this:

```
const myArray = [1,2,3]
```

Depending on the length of this array (which keeps changing only between 2 and 3), I want to add or remove a `react-native-svg` component which display this value.

This is how I have approached it so far (I know this code will not work):

```
const myComponent = (props) => {
    const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([1,2,3]);

    const mySVGComponents = useEffect(() => {
        //It is ensured that the array has at least two values
        let GroupWrapper = (() => {
            return (
                <G>
                    <SVGText>{myArray[0]}</SVGText>
                    <SVGText>{myArray[1]}</SVGText>
                </G>
            )
        })

        if (myArray.length === 3) {
            GroupWrapper = (() => {
                return (
                    <GroupWrapper>
                        <SVGText>{myArray[2]}</SVGText>
                    </GroupWrapper>
                )
            })
        }

        return GroupWrapper;

    }, [myArray]);

    return (
        <G>
            {mySVGComponents}
        </G>
    )
}
```

How can I inject `SVGText` components into the `<G>` component conditionally based on the length of `myArray`?

Comment: In case the array length is 3, you need three `SVGText` inside a `G` and if it is 2, you need just just 2?

Comment: Yes, this is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rendering an array of items in React is not as complicated as you are trying to do it here. You can read mode about that here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Specifically for your case, you first have to remove the useEffect, you are not supposed to use it like that (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). All you have to do is just map the array in the return statement, take a look at this:

```
export const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([1,2,3]);
    return <G>{myArray.map(item => <SVGText key={item}>{item}</SVGText>)}</G>;
}
```

This way you are rendering each item in the array, and it will be automatically rerendered when you update you array using setMyArray.

Comment: OK, this was kind of obvious and I did not see it. But regarding your statement about not using `useEffect()`: I only want to re-render the `<G>` when `myArray` changes. So shouldn't I use `useEffect` for this case then? Also: I have specific attributes assigned to each of the `SVGText` components, that differ from each other. So with your solution I probably should store those in a different array then (?)

Comment: @JoeBe this component will only rerender when myArray or some props change. If you really want to cache the rendered array you can use useMemo (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) but it really isn't needed in this case. 

How are you storing your attributes now for each item? Usually you have to store them together with the items and make myArray an array of objects. You can also store them separately if you want to.

Answer (score -1):

Only change your "mySVGComponents" to below given code.

```
const mySVGComponents = useEffect(() => {
            //It is ensured that the array has at least two values

             let GroupWrapper = (() => {

               return (
                    <G>
                      {
                       myArray.map(item => <SVGText>{item}</SVGText>)
                      }  
                    </G>
                )
            })
            return GroupWrapper;

        }, [myArray]);
```